# Как настроить расположение кнопок?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить равномерное расположение кнопок?

В старой редакции все было аккуратно:

_http://vikomed-54.ru/

В новой редакции кнопки постоянно пляшут:

1. Кнопки прижались друг к другу

_http://sib-fitting.ru/blog/

2. Кнопки разъехались:

_http://sibiryak-54.ru/uslugi/

Answer (score 3):

Дело не в версии яндекс-кнопок, у вас применяются общие стили для элементов, в частности для тегов `a` и `li`, то есть, в иерархии стилей вы используете правила для всех тегов, которые находятся внутри определённого блока, и ваши стили перекрывают первоначальные стили яндекс-кнопок. Если отключить общие правила, кнопки выглядят нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]